# Passing list<T> or array as argument of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, collections

If I do this will I still be guaranteed the order that was present in the original collection?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: @David Arno I have tried it - and it appears to be ordered correctly for those few times I've tried, but that's no proof that it's GUARANTEED every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.
All you're doing is an implicit cast to an interface - it has absolutely no effect on the underlying object.

**Edit**

Actually, casting "a" object to one of its interfaces *may* have side effects. Value types, when casted to an interface, are boxed.
But since `List<T>` and arrays are reference types, there are no side effects.

Comment: Thanks - so basically IEnumerable cannot guarantee ordering because ultimately it depends on whether the underlying collection type does?

Comment: Exactly. `IEnumerable` is an interface, it has no implementation code - therefore, there are no guarantees. Interfaces guarantee one thing and one thing only - the underlying object will implement those methods. For example, `IEnumerable` can only guarantee that any underlying object will have its own implement of the `GetEnumerator` method.